# Two integrals involving $\sqrt{\cosh x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have two integrals on my table which I can can calculate numerically, but would have been happy to see whether they have closed form or values in terms of "standard" known functions: $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{\sqrt{\cosh x}}dx \quad \text{for} \quad a=1,3.$$
I appreciate your hints. Many thanks.

Note: By standard here I mean any (well-)known function that are in general available in most math software packages.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Bx%2F(Sqrt%5Bcosh%5Bx%5D%5D),x%5D

Now take limits

Comment: @tired Many thanks :-) Do you mean I am hopeless in getting a neat and nice form?

Comment: you can formulate it like that ^^

Comment: I am not sure why my question should be closed :-) what context should I add here so that the question is not closed?

Comment: I don't know, I upvoted it, looks like a fine question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \color{red}{I(a)}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^a}{\sqrt{\cosh x}}\,dx &=& \sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^a e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{1+e^{-2x}}}\,dx\\&=&\sqrt{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^a e^{-x/2}e^{-2n x}\,dx\\&=&\color{red}{a!\sqrt{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{a+1}}\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the last series is a hypergeometric series related with the generating function of Catalan numbers. In particular, for $a=1$ we get:
$$ I(1) = 4\sqrt{2}\;\phantom{}_3 F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right)\tag{2} $$
and for $a=3$ we get:
$$ I(3)= 96\sqrt{2}\;\phantom{}_5 F_4\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right).\tag{3} $$
It is interesting to point out that for $a=0$ we have the simple closed form
$$ I(0) = \color{red}{\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2 }\tag{4}$$
since the associated $\phantom{}_2 F_1$ function is given by an elliptic integral that can be computed through [Euler's beta function](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzione_beta_di_Eulero):

$$ I(0)=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^3+t}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^3+t}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^3+t}}\stackrel{t=z^2}{=}\color{red}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^4+1}}}. $$

Comment: Nice answer (as usual !). Cheers

Comment: Thanks! what I was doing was to write $(\cosh x)^{-1/2}=\sqrt{2} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\frac12}{j}e^{-(2j+1/2)x}$ and proceed with integration, which I could not finish! Many thanks for the nice insight!

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity and the fun.*

Let $$I_a=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{\sqrt{\cosh x}}dx $$

Here are the "nice" formulas given by a CAS
$$I_0=4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2$$
$$I_1=\sqrt{2} \left(\frac{8}{25} \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};\frac{9}{4},\frac{9}{4};-1\right)
   -\frac{4}{5} \sqrt[4]{58 \sqrt{2}-82} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{9}{4};\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+4\right)$$
$$I_2=16 \sqrt{2} \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{
   4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right)$$
$$I_3=96 \sqrt{2} \,
   _5F_4\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{
   4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right)$$
$$I_4=768 \sqrt{2} \,
   _6F_5\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{
   2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right)$$
$$I_5=7680 \sqrt{2} \,
   _7F_6\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{
   4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac
   {5}{4};-1\right)$$

$$I_6=92160 \sqrt{2} \,
   _8F_7\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{
   4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac
   {5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right)$$

$$I_7=1290240 \sqrt{2} \,
   _9F_8\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{
   4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac
   {5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right)$$
$$I_8=20643840 \sqrt{2} \,
   _{10}F_9\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{
   1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4   };-1\right)$$

For $a\geq 2$, there is a nice pattern. Concerning the leading coefficient, it corresponds to sequences $A032184$ and $A066318$ at OEIS.

Comment: I have not been able to simplify $I_1$. Jack D'Aurizio's answer has it and makes everuthing in the same frame.

Comment: This looks neat :-) many thanks!

Comment: @Math-fun. Because of your user name, I ran a CAS for the **fun of math**

Comment: well math is a very fun and nice and one can play around with it. It make a lot of fun to scribble :-)